# git push... fatal: Unable to create master.lock: File exists

Tags: git, repository

Help!  When I try to do a `git push origin master` now, I get:

```
fatal: Unable to create '/home/ubuntu/workspace/.git/refs/remotes/origin/master.lock': File exists.
If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
```

Of course, I've found other similar questions (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282632/git-index-lock-file-exists-when-i-try-to-commit-but-cannot-delete-the-file)), but the upvoted answers in there merely suggest deleting the offending file... but the file does not exist!

I fear that this is happening after I recently tried to clear some space using the following:

```
$ sudo git reflog expire --all --expire=now
$ sudo git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

Could that be the cause?  Any suggestions for a fix?

Comment: If the file really does not exist, something bizarre is happening in error handling, as the error message should read `No such file or directory` (i.e., `ENOENT`, not `EEXIST`).  The most likely problem after using `sudo`, though, is that you have part of your repository owned by you, and part owned by the super-user, and since you are not the super-user, you no longer have permission to touch your repository.  Of course in this case the error should be `EPERM`, `Permission denied`...!

Comment: @torek, oh dear!  Any fix for this?

Comment: Well, first, the question is whether this really is the problem.  You could use `ls -lR` (recursive `ls -l`) to see if ownership is mixed-up.  If so, since you obviously have sudo, you can `sudo chown -R <yourself> .` to put all the ownership back to yourself.

Comment: @torek where should I do that, in the .git folder?

Comment: Given the two commands you ran should only touch things in `.git`, yes (though if it were me I'd run `find . -user root` or `find . ! -user <me>` as a shortcut for the `ls`, just to see if I'd done something else equally silly elsewhere, doing the `find` as high up as necessary for comfort...).

Comment: @torek I see mostly 'ubuntu'... but a few are 'root', including the `.git/refs/remotes/origin` folder...

Comment: Presumably you are logged in as `ubuntu` then (or the files are supposed to be owned by `ubuntu` at least), so that would be the `<yoursellf>` part to fill in, and you could run it on all of `.git` or just on `.git/refs/remotes`.  The expires should not have created any new objects, just modified reflogs and refs.

Comment: I'm using Cloud9 so assume you're right... I'm logged in as `ubuntu` so I'll try that.

Comment: @torek you are a lifesaver!  Worked like a charm!  In the `.git` folder I did `sudo chown ubuntu:ubuntu . -R`, then back in the repo folder `git push origin master` is working fine again!  Please can you add an Answer so that I can credit you?  Also, should I have just done the `git reflog` and `git gc` without `sudo`?  There is nothing intrinsically bad about doing `gc` and `reflog`, just that I shouldn't have used `sudo`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem appears to have stemmed from running the expiration code as the super-user (`sudo ...`).  When Git adjusted the remote-tracking branch files, they became owned by (and hence only adjustable by) the super-user.

The fix is to put those files back to the correct owner (in this case `ubuntu`).  One can use a blanket ownership-change, e.g., `sudo chown -R ubuntu .git`, or a selective one (change only mis-owned files), e.g., as root (or with `sudo` again, this one is a bit more annoying because of the pipeline) `find .git -user root -print0 | xargs -0 chown ubuntu`.  The only difference, if any, between these would be that `chown -R` might update more files' `ctime` (inode-change time) fields (by actually running `chown` system calls on files already properly owned), which can in turn affect backup systems.

The more general rule is "don't arbitrarily prefix stuff with `sudo`"—in this case, there was no reason to put `sudo` in front of the `git reflog expire` and `git gc` commands.