# Github Wiki Question - I want to push remote-repository's wiki.git to my github repository, but it doesnt' work

Tags: git, github, wiki

when I tried under in linux terminal,
`git push origin +master`

I saw this error

```
error: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master': cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master': Unable to create '/home/[myfile_route]/.git/refs/remotes/origin/master.lock': Permission denied
```

I think the reason is, that my github repository is locked repository-only I can see. Is it right? or if it's wrong, why this happened?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git push ERROR: Unable to create '.git/refs/remotes/jr/master.lock': File exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52323860/git-push-error-unable-to-create-git-refs-remotes-jr-master-lock-file-exists)

Comment: `origin` does not appear to be on GitHub at all. What does `git remote -v` print?

Comment: `I tried git remote -v` , and 
origin https://github.com/~/~.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/~/~.git (push)
is comes out

Comment: I tried rm -f , but it doesn't work